# Convert 3-byte ascii signature format to image

Tags: .net, decode

I am using a Ingenico i6580 pinpad machine and am retrieving the customer's signature in the default 3-byte ascii signature format. I coding in VB.NET using VS2010. Does anyone know if there is a utility that can convert this format back into an image?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the default Convert format"?

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong line, there are 2 supposed output fomats... • SIG_BIN_2 (3-byte ASCII Signature Format)
• SIG_RAW_4 (4-byte Raw Signature Format)

Comment: Do you have any documentation or links for these? It doesn't sound like they're really full image formats... you don't have much room in 3 bytes!

Comment: Its more of a three byte sequence here is an exert in the documentation...

Coordinate data is organized into segments of pen-down data. Each segment is started by a special control
code that identifies the local region of signature space to begin the segment. This is called the Segment
Start character. The Segment Start character is followed by a variable number of coordinate data
sets that describe the pen movement throughout the pen-down segment.
Each coordinate data set consists of 3 characters describing the

Comment: position of the pen relative to its position
described by the immediately preceding coordinate data set. The segment is concluded if a pen-up condition
occurs or if two successive coordinate points are separated by a distance that exceeds the range capabilities
of the 3 character coordinate data set format. A pen-up condition is marked by a special Pen-Up
character. Coordinate data is not scaled in this format. Only ASCII characters in the range of 20 hex to 7E
hex are used.

Comment: Have been searching but have not found much, it seems that I may have to build my own utility to piece this back together.

Comment: Ah, I see. It sounds like you probably want to start with an empty bitmap and "redraw" the lines etc.

Comment: Haha thats what I am afraid of

Comment: Can you give us an example of actual signature data?  This doesn't actually sound too hard to decode.

Comment: Pen position within the signature image space is described by an X position coordinate and a Y position
coordinate. Each of these numbers is eleven bits in length, X10 through X0 for the X coordinate and Y10
through Y0 for the Y coordinate. The starting position of a segment is given by the data found in the
SEGMENT START character and the data found in the first coordinate data set. The Segment Start character
provides bits X10, X9, Y10, and Y9 of the starting position. To these characters are appended bits
x8 through x0 and y8 through y0 which are found in the first coordinate data set.

Comment: Each succeeding coordinate data set provides an offset for X and for Y that should be added to the previous
coordinate values to form the next eleven bit coordinate value. The X and Y offsets consist of 9 bit
values and can be positive or negative. The offset values are coded in 2’s that complement notation with
the sign bit in the most significant position. Sign bit extension to the 10th and 11th bits must be performed
when adding the 9 bit offset values to the previous 11 bit coordinate values.

Comment: @JBone: You should be placing all of this in the question, and not in the comments.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eKNZH2xs - Would be some sample data...

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is very old, but I hope this can be helpful to someone in the future.

Documentation for the SigBin2 format can be found [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/3-byte-ascii-doc.295002/).

Also, [this forum post](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?807919-RESOLVED-Need-to-Convert-ASCII-3-Byte-Signature-Format-to-Image&p=5527891#post5527891) was very helpful for me when working through this issue.

Here's my final code for rendering an a SigBin2 signature to an image:

```
private Bitmap sigBinToImage(string sigBin2Source, float scaleFactor)
{
    // Compute all the points for each of the segments in the signature
    List<List<Point>> pointLists = sigBinToPoints(sigBin2Source);

    // Draw the signature
    Bitmap signatureImage = pointsToImage(pointLists, scaleFactor);

    return signatureImage;
}

private List<List<Point>> sigBinToPoints(string sigBin2Source)
{
    /*
     * The SigBin2 format (also called 3-byte Ascii format) is a relative coordinate format.
     * The format is structured as follows:
     *   1) Segment Start control character
     *        An ascii character in the range 96-111 containing bits used to determine the
     *        starting position of the line segment (pen stroke).
     *        
     *   2) Coordinate Data Character 1
     *        An ascii character in the range 32-95 containing bits used to determine the
     *        X-offset from the last coordinate.
     *        Note that the ascii value has to be shifted down by 32 before being used.
     *        
     *   3) Coordinate Data Character 2
     *        An ascii character in the range 32-95 containing bits used to determine the
     *        Y-offset from the last coordinate
     *        Note that the ascii value has to be shifted down by 32 before being used.
     *        
     *   4) Coordinate Data Character 3
     *        An ascii character in the range 32-95 containing bits used to determine the
     *        remaining bits of the X-offset and Y-offset from the last coordinate
     *        Note that the ascii value has to be shifted down by 32 before being used.
     *        
     *   *) Items (2), (3), and (4) are repeated for all datapoints in the line segment (pen stroke).
     *   
     *   5) Pen Up control character
     *        An ascii character (112) signaling that the line segment (pen stroke) has ended
     *        
     *   *) Items (1) through (5) are repeated for all line segments (pen strokes)
     *   
     * More information about this format can be found here:
     *   https://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/3-byte-ascii-doc.295002/
     */


    short cX = 0, cY = 0;               // Absolute coordinate of last datapoint
    short dX = 0, dY = 0;               // Offset from last datapoint
    int parseMode = 0;                  // The type of character we are expecting next
    bool firstPointInSegment = false;   // Disables sign-extension for the first coordinate in the segment

    List<List<Point>> points = new List<List<Point>>();

    // Loop through all characters in the SigBin2 string
    for (int i = 0; i < sigBin2Source.Length; i++)
    {
        short asciiValue = (short)sigBin2Source[i];
        switch (asciiValue)
        {
            case object _ when asciiValue >= 0x60 && asciiValue <= 0x6F:   // Segment Start control character
                if (parseMode == 0)
                {
                    // Get the start position bits (b3 = X10, b2 = X9, b1 = Y10, b0 = Y9)
                    cX = (short)((asciiValue & 0xC) << 7);
                    cY = (short)((asciiValue & 0x3) << 9);

                    // Look for the first byte of the 3-byte coordinate
                    parseMode = 1;

                    // Ignore relative offset for the first point of the sequence
                    firstPointInSegment = true;

                    // Allocate new list for this segment's points
                    points.Add(new List<Point>());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Segment Start character is in an invalid position (a Pen Up character needs to precede it)
                    throw new Exception($"Illegal Segment Start character '{sigBin2Source[i].ToString()}' at position {i.ToString()}");
                }

                break;

            case object _ when asciiValue >= 0x20 && asciiValue <= 0x5F:   // Part of a 3-byte coordinate
                // Check which byte of the 3-byte coordinate that this is
                // Note: ascii values are offset by 0x20
                if (parseMode == 1)   // First byte
                {
                    // Get X-bits 3 to 8 (bits 0 to 5 of asciiValue)
                    dX = (short)((asciiValue - 0x20) << 3);

                    // Look for the second byte
                    parseMode = 2;
                }
                else if (parseMode == 2)   // Second byte
                {
                    // Get Y-bits 3 to 8 (bits 0 to 5 of asciiValue)
                    dY = (short)((asciiValue - 0x20) << 3);

                    // Look for the third byte
                    parseMode = 3;
                }
                else if (parseMode == 3)   // Third byte
                {
                    // Mask bits 0 to 5 (for safety) and shift ascii value
                    asciiValue = (short)((asciiValue - 0x20) & 0x3F);

                    // Get X bits 0 to 2 (bits 3 to 5 of asciiValue)
                    dX = (short)(dX | ((asciiValue >> 3) & 0x7));

                    // Get Y bits 0 to 2 (bits 0 to 2 of asciiValue)
                    dY = (short)(dY | (asciiValue & 0x7));

                    // Sign extend
                    if (!firstPointInSegment)   // Don't sign-extend offsets for the first point in the segment
                    {
                        // If sign bit is 1, sign-extend to bits 9-15 to make it a negative short
                        if (dX > 255)
                            dX = (short)(dX | 0xFE00);
                        if (dY > 255)
                            dY = (short)(dY | 0xFE00);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstPointInSegment = false;
                    }

                    // Add the coordinate offset to the last absolute coordinate
                    cX += dX;
                    cY += dY;

                    // Add this point to the list
                    points[points.Count - 1].Add(new Point(cX, cY));

                    // Assume the next character will be the first byte of another 3-byte coordinate
                    parseMode = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Coordinate character is in invalid position (a Segment Start character needs to preceed it)
                    throw new Exception($"Illegal Coordinate character '{sigBin2Source[i].ToString()}' at position {i.ToString()}");
                }

                break;

            case 0x70:   // Pen Up control character
                if (parseMode == 1)
                {
                    // Look for the next Segment Start control character
                    parseMode = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Pen Up character is in invalid position (the preceding coordinate needs to be complete)
                    throw new Exception($"Illegal Pen Up character '{sigBin2Source[i].ToString()}' at position {i.ToString()}");
                }

                break;

            default:   // Unrecognized character
                throw new Exception($"Unrecognized character '{sigBin2Source[i].ToString()}' at position {i.ToString()} (mode: {parseMode.ToString()})");
        }
    }

    // Return the list of coordinate points
    return points;
}

private Bitmap pointsToImage(List<List<Point>> pointLists, float scaleFactor)
{
    // Find the max and min points
    int minX = int.MaxValue, maxX = int.MinValue, minY = int.MaxValue, maxY = int.MinValue;
    foreach (List<Point> pointList in pointLists) {
        foreach (Point p in pointList)
        {
            if (p.X > maxX)
                maxX = p.X;
            if (p.X < minX)
                minX = p.X;
            if (p.Y > maxY)
                maxY = p.Y;
            if (p.Y < minY)
                minY = p.Y;
        }
    }

    // Create a bitmap from the computed dimensions (with some padding around the edges)
    int edgePaddingBase = 5;
    int edgePadding = (int)((float)edgePaddingBase * scaleFactor);
    int imgWidth = (int)((float)(maxX - minX) * scaleFactor) + (edgePadding * 2);
    int imgHeight = (int)((float)(maxY - minY) * scaleFactor) + (edgePadding * 2);
    Bitmap signatureImg = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight);

    // Setup drawing settings
    //   Note that the Y-axis is flipped
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(signatureImg);
    g.ScaleTransform(scaleFactor, -1F * scaleFactor);
    g.TranslateTransform((-1 * minX) + edgePaddingBase, (-1 * minY) + -1.0F * (maxY - minY) - edgePaddingBase);
    g.Clear(Color.White);

    // Draw each of the segments on the image
    foreach (List<Point> pointList in pointLists)
        g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, pointList.ToArray<Point>());

    g.Dispose();

    // Return the signature image
    return signatureImg;
}
```

One thing to note is make sure that you un-escape your SigBin string before processing it. If you received the signature data in a JSON file, the SigBin string is most likely going to be escaped. For example, in JSON, a quote " is represented with \" so you must ensure that the string is un-escaped before being processed. [This](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output) page is useful for un-escaping your SigBin string. However, be aware that this tool will sometimes interpret things as escapes that weren't actually intended to be escapes. If you're getting "Illegal Character Position" exceptions with my code, escapes are most likely the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this C# function to draw the image on a PictureEdit (a DevExpress control)

```
 public void getSignGraph(string signatureData)
    {
        var stringOfPoints = signatureData.Split(',');
        var beginStroke = true;
        //PictureEdit1 is a DevExpress control where the image will be drawn
        using (Graphics g = PictureEdit1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            var keepx = "";
            var keepy = "";
            foreach (var pointval in stringOfPoints)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pointval))
                {
                    var point = pointval.Split(',');
                    var x = point[0];
                    var y = point[1];

                    if (x == "#" && y == "#")
                    {
                        beginStroke = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (beginStroke)
                        {
                            beginStroke = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(Convert.ToInt32(keepx), Convert.ToInt32(keepy)), new Point(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y)));
                        }
                    }
                    keepx = x;
                    keepy = y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```